# Login with FB, ASP.NET, and login event. How?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, authentication

I'm a developer of 5 years, so I am no stranger to asp.net, but I am new to JQuery and JSON, so maybe that's why I'm not getting it.  I followed the tutorial here about how to successfully login with facebook, and it works!
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/450535/Using-Facebook-login-in-ASP-NET-application-withou

but my problem is that I am making a "comments" system on my site, and I want to user to type in their comment, then right below it click the "login with facebook" button, then when it successfully logs in, have it append the comment to the list of comments.

My only problem is I don't know how to get the Login to trigger C# code on the server side.  Am I missing something here in order to hook into the "login successful" event of facebook?

I suspect it has something to do with these lines of code here:

```
enter codedd here

// This method will be called after the user login into facebook.
    function OnLogin(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,gender,email,birthday', LoadValues);                    
        }
    }

    //This method will load the values to the labels
    function LoadValues (me) {
        if (me.name) {
            document.getElementById('displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
            document.getElementById('FBId').innerHTML = me.id;
            document.getElementById('DisplayEmail').innerHTML = me.email;
            document.getElementById('Gender').innerHTML = me.gender;
            document.getElementById('DOB').innerHTML = me.birthday;
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
                        }
    }
```

or here:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> <!-- This initializes the FB controls-->   
<div class="fb-login-button" autologoutlink="true" scope="user_birthday,email" >
  Login with Facebook
 </div> <!-- FB Login Button -->   
<!-- Details --> 
<div id="auth-status">    
<div id="auth-loggedin" style="display: none">
    Hi, <span id="displayname"></span><br/>
    Your Facebook ID : <span id="FBId"></span><br/>
    Your Email : <span id="DisplayEmail"></span><br/>
    Your Sex:, <span id="Gender"></span><br/>
    Your Date of Birth :, <span id="DOB"></span><br/>        
</div>
</div>
```

any clues or help would be greatly appreciated. I'm a very long time lurker (maybe 10 years?) , first time poster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the first thing that comes to my mind it is not a perfect solution but it might work in this scenario. In short **trigger a PostBack with a dummy button clicking it with Javascript at the correct place**(not by user's click).

1) Put an asp.net button (runat=server) somewhere on your page. It will be a dummy button just to trigger a postback so make its width = 0 or something like that. Lets call it **btnDummmy**. Make **ClientIDMode=static**.

2) Attach a **server side event to btnDummy**. Put your server-side comment save logic there. The **comment should be in a asp.net textbox** (runat=server).

3) Put btnDummy also in an **updatePanel**. (So that you do not lose the span values, displayname, FBId, blabla)

4) When you login with Facebook at the end of LoadValues(me) before returning call **btnDummy.click()**;

This should do the trick...

Comment: That worked as far as getting the button to be clicked "on log in" which is awesome.  My next task is to see if I can extract the value from 
    <span id="displayname"></span>
any ideas?
Thanks for the help  so far

Comment: Continue the same way... Add 5 more asp.net textboxes or hiddenfields (which would be better) (txtdisplayname, txtFBId,...) whose widths are "0" (not visible to user) and clientidmodes are static. When you fill the <span> tags at the LoadValues function fill also those textboxes/hiddenfields. Then you'll be able to read their values when btnDummy is clicked...

Comment: I did that but it didnt seem to work for me?
I added 
        document.getElementById('trestid').innerHTML = me.name;
        document.getElementById("btnDummy").click();
to the FB portion

Comment: and I added  <asp:TextBox ID="trestid" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> to the FB markup section

Am I missing anything? 
PS. this mini reply box sux for formatting text lol

Comment: could it be the runat="server" messing things up for me? Or maybe the fact that it's not in an update panel too or something?

Comment: AHA! even though the INTELLISENSE didn't suggest it, I need to use
document.getElementById("trestid").value = me.name; . .VALUE. I had even started typing .VAL but when the intellisense didnt suggest it, I used innerHTML instead.
THANKS ERICH007!